# How to use Subdomain And Main Domain in Same Laravel Aplication

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6.* . Now I created saparate route for sub domian and main domain. also create middleware for subdomain. But when I browse my site its get error with "Missing required parameters for [Route: something] [URI: something]"

My Route file

```php
$domain = '{s_domain}.' . parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_HOST);
Route::group(['domain' => $domain, 'middleware' => 'subdomain'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Clients', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', 'ClientDashboardController@index')->name('home');
    });
});

$maindomain = parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_HOST);
Route::group(['domain' => $maindomain], function () {
    // My Route
});
```

My Subdomain Middlware file

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $subdomain = $request->route()->s_domain;

    $customer = Customer::where( 'sub_domain', $subdomain )->where('status', 'On')->first();

    if( ! $customer ) {
        return redirect()->route('customer.inactive');
    } else {

        Config::set('database.connections.subdomain.database', $customer->customer_database);
        Config::set('database.default', 'subdomain');
        \DB::purge('subdomain');
        \DB::reconnect('subdomain');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Please show us the actual errors, and the relevant routes. You've censored all the useful info here.

Comment: `Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login]. (View: F:\wamp64\www\ispsoft\system\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)` I got this error

Comment: Where is your `login` route defined?

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: `<form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">` Its define in my login.blade.php

Comment: Take `Auth::routes();` out of the `Route::group`. Putting it in the group means the route expects the domain as the first parameter, but the built-in login route won't know that.

Comment: its not only login route. All route wants parameter

Comment: Yes, any routes you put in the group will need to be adjusted to handle the domain in their controller functions. Calling a function within a `Route::group` with domain/subdomain routing means you have to adjust the function's arguments accordingly.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Right now i have to use this everytime i call route() function.

    `<a href="{ route( 'app.home', $subdomain ) }">Dashboard</a>`

Is there any way to assign a current subdomain value to the subdomain parameter and make it work by directly calling the function, Instead of adding it every time?, Something like this.

    `<a href="{ route( 'app.home') }">Dashboard</a>`